# Uploading and saving multiple images in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload multiple image and save them as different sizes in Laravel 4.

The issue is, while I'm trying to make a full res and thumbnail sized copy of each image, it only resizes and saves the first one.

I'm using the `Intervention` php image class to handle resizing etc.

#### My code:

**HTML form**

`<input type="file" name="photo[]">`

**Laravel Code**

```
$photos = Input::file('photo');

$photoTypes = array(
  'full_res' => [612, 75],
   'thumbnail' => [150, 60]
);

    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $originalPhoto = $photo;

        foreach ($photoTypes as $type => $size) {
            print "Photo upload loop";
            $photo = $originalPhoto->getRealPath();
            $path = 'img/'. sha1(microtime()) . '.jpg';
            $photo = Image::make($photo);
            $photo->resize($size[0], $size[0], false);
            $photo->encode('jpg', $size[1]);
            $photo->save($path);

            $photoDB = new Photo();
            $photoDB->user_id = $user_id;
            $photoDB->item_id = $item->id;
            $photoDB->type = $type;
            $photoDB->url = $path;
            $photoDB->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you're overwriting the $photo variable in your Foreach of $photoTypes.  Try renaming that variable.  Try to avoid re-using variable names inside loops as it can cause issues.  I'm not sure that will solve your issue but it might prevent further issues from developing.